# having trouble putting the submit button at the bottom. It is on the side, by the comment box instead of below comment box

Tags: html, css, forms

I created a jfiddle.  I'm sure it is easy to fix, but I can't figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/mt4jK/8/

```
  <h1 class="allpages">Questions or Concerns about Compliance Issues?</h1>
  <h3>We welcome all compliments and constructive criticism!</h3>

    <form class="webform" action="http://hsc.unm.edu/scripts/cfmailform/cfmailer.cfm" method="post">
    <!--Required hidden operators--> 
    <input name="recipient" type="hidden" value="bfloran@salud.unm.edu" />
    <input name="subject" type="hidden" value="HSC Compliance Office Email Form" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cc" value="mgwilson@salud.unm.edu" />

    <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="http://hsc.unm.edu/admin/compliance/ThankYOU.html" /> <!-- Field validation for the user -->
```

```
 <label for "name">Your Name (optional):</label>

  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" /><br />
  <label for "name">Your E-mail (Optional):</label>



  <input name="mail" type="text" value="" /><br>
  <label for "name">Comment:</label>
  <textarea name="comment" value="" ></textarea>
  <p>
  <div class="submit">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </div>
  </form>
```

CSS:

```
h3{text-align:center;}
.webform {background-color: #eeeeee; 
 width: 655px;  border: solid;
 border-color: #e9e9e9;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 15px 0px 15px     17px;}
.webform  label { width:200px; vertical-align:top; text-align:right; padding: 5px;    float:left; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;}
 .webform textarea {width:200px; text-align:right; float:left; }
 .submit{width:50px:}
```

edit: formatting the CSS code to easy visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a float:left in textarea remove it like this:

```
.webform textarea {width:200px; text-align:right;  }
```

instead of this:

```
.webform textarea {width:200px; text-align:right; float:left; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mt4jK/9/)

Comment: thank you! I was thinking that float was needed for something else..thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you! no float is needed when you have to align for example two div in the same line. @user2196989 Remind to accept (when you can) the answer if solved your problem to help other guys with your same problem please

Comment: you have accept the answer this is the way to help other guys with your same problem, this is how stackoverflow works :) @user2196989

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the margin-bottom of your comment boxes is messing with the .submit div. I found that adding some margin top to your .submit wrapper pushes it far enough down to clear the other container's margin-bottom. Try adding this to your ".submit" class:

css:

```
width: 230px;
margin: 50px auto;
```